# XCode: Debug => "Simulate Location" menu item not available (greyed out)

Tags: xcode, debugging, geolocation

I cannot seem to add any simulated location to the simulator, as the corresponding menu is completely greyed out, as shown in figure:

[image]

the location works well when debugging with the actual device.

any idea?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The iOS Simulator must be running your app before that menu will be enabled. For me it appears immediately after a successful build.

If it's proving inconvenient to make a selection in that menu between build of your app and it's launch, I would recommend setting a default location via Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme. You can then select your preferred default in the Run / Options panel after checking the "Allow Location Simulation" box.

[image: Xcode : Default location option]

Comment: Thank you for this!  I had it working, then upgraded Xcode and I had to perform this. Default Location was selected to None. Why did it change during upgrade?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that it works only if your `Build Configuration` is on `Debug` (as you can see in the screenshot), it doesn't work if you switch to `Release`.

Comment: This also was the solution for me when I was fighting a problem where `Debug > Simulate Location` was always getting set back to the same simulated location (instead of "None") at the beginning of each run of my app (on a real iPhone device).